# Animation in Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qml, qtdeclarative

I'm trying to make a slow change of color in my code but my program waits for 1.5 secs and then changes color instantly. My development environment is Windows 8. How can i fix this? Here is my code:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "green"
    width: 300
    height: 300
    ColorAnimation on color {
        to: "red"
        duration: 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Is your application QML-only?  If not, it could be something in the C++ layer blocking for 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Is the delay exactly 1.5 sec? How did you measure that? This code is very simple and have to work without problem. Post please all the code related to this problem.

Comment: My version of Qt is 4.8.5. 
No, i'm creating Qt Quick application (with main.cpp and etc). And this is while code.